# Opera на смартфоне режет контент ssl-страницы при переходе в полноэкранный режим

Tags: python, apache, ssl, opera

Сайт работает по порту 80. Работает без ошибок. Но как только он открывается на мобильном устройстве с поддержкой SSL (только на смартфонах, в частности, MEIZU, LG) и переводится в полноэкранный режим встроенной кнопочкой, отрезается нижняя часть экрана и страница перестает работать.

Особенность - сертификат SSL/TLS самоподписанный.

Сервер:
Windows, Apache 2.4, Python 3, Flask.

Планшет (Samsung, GT-P3100, Android 4.2.2, старенький) работает. Правда, там нет полноэкранного режима. ПК работает.

Может ли быть проблема в сертификате? Прошу любых рекомендаций. Ничего не помогает. Тесты провел на самом простом контенте, нет ни js, ни крутого css, одни html-теги. Поведение одинаковое во всех случаях.

Проявление замечено в браузере Opera (в одной из последних версий), Chrome работает.

Могут ли проблемы быть связаны с самопальным сертификатом? Сертификат создавал несколькими способами, в частности, описанными в [инструкции](http://adminsnotes.blogspot.com/2008/01/apache-openssl-windows.html), с настройкой Apache и без, в том числе, встроенными методами Flask [техника Werkzeug](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/serving/).

Flask app (manage.py):

```py
@manager.command
def start():
    """Run server."""
    #ssl_context = 'adhoc'
    ssl_context = ('secure/ssl.crt', 'secure/ssl.key')
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True, ssl_context=ssl_context)
```

Извиняюсь за качество изображений, другие не умею делать;).

До перехода в полноэкранный режим:

[image: до]

Нажимаю кнопочку самую последнюю в правом нижнем углу:

[image: после]

На странице кнопки, не работают. Вернуть в рабочее состояние невозможно, только открыть заново. Правда, это более "сложная" страница, с любой страницей один и тот же эффект.

В варианте "чистого" http://... таких проблем нет. Все открыл, страница работает:

[image: страница в полноэкранном режиме без SSL]

Снимки со смартфона MEIZU M5s, модель M612H, Android 6.0, версия прошивки Flyme 6.3.1.0G от 5.02.2018.

Т.е. то, что он открыл "до" - открывает и "после", ни строчкой больше.

Comment: Уточняю, при переходе на SSL, в Apache - порт 443, во Flask - 5000, но по моему порт тут ни при чем.

Comment: Проверил Safari, Dolphin. Работают. Выходит - какая-то странная особенность мобильного браузера Opera. Баг?